TypeError: Gym_App.handle_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
Im trying to use the Twilio message API to send and receive message from Whatsapp. I tried to refactorize to a class. When i try to run the app it runs correctly, but when the user send a message to the app it give me the error. heres the code:
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
from twilio.rest import Client
from database import Connection

 
app = Flask(__name__)
load_dotenv()     
client = Client()
connection = Connection

class Twilio:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
          pass

    def respond(self,message):
            # "chatbot" responde al mensaje del usuario
            response = MessagingResponse()
            response.message(message)
            return str(response)

    def reply(self,message:str):
        print(message)
        if message:
            # Server send message
            return self.respond(message) 
        
class Gym_App:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.tapp = Twilio()


    @app.route('/message', methods=['POST'])
    def handle_message(self):
        
        # client side message
        message = request.form.get('Body').lower()
        return self.tapp.reply(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gapp = Gym_App()
    gapp.handle_message()

I worked perfectly, but when i try to use it as different classes, the decorator makes a conflict with self parameter, i know the reasons, but i can't figure out how to solve the problem. What should i do?

I don't thnk @app.route() works in methods.

Flask's Flask object is designed to wrap functions, not methods.  You won't have more than one instance of Gym_App, instead of building a class, you can just move the Twilio app reference to the global scope.
TWILIO_APP = Twilio()

@app.route('/message', methods=['POST'])
def gym_handle_message():
    # client side message
    message = request.form.get('Body').lower()
    return TWILIO_APP.reply(message)

However, if you are determined to wrap this into a class, then you will need a decorator that can pass-through the self argument for each method.  The problem is that decorators in Python are evaluated at compile-time, not during run-time.  So the app.route decorator is adding the class method of Gym_App.handle_message to the route rules, and not the instance methods of gapp.handle_message.
